# how to make Jquery swipe function work on whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swipe

I have follow this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_event_swiperight) to create a swipe right function. However, this only work when you swipe right inside the text. How to make the swipe right function triggered when I swipe right at any location of this page. Thanks!

```js
    $(document).on("pagecreate","#pageone",function(){
      $("p").on("swiperight",function(){
        $(this).hide();
      });                       
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>The swiperight Event</h1>
      </div>
    
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>If you swipe me in the right direction, I will disappear.</p>
        <p>Swipe me in the right direction!</p>
        <p>Swipe me in the right direction, too!</p>
      </div>
    
      <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer Text</h1>
      </div>
    </div> 
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the "swiperight" on #pageone?

```js
    $(document).on("pagecreate","#pageone",function(){
      $("#pageone").on("swiperight",function(){
        $(this).hide();
      });                       
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>The swiperight Event</h1>
      </div>
    
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>If you swipe me in the right direction, I will disappear.</p>
        <p>Swipe me in the right direction!</p>
        <p>Swipe me in the right direction, too!</p>
      </div>
    
      <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer Text</h1>
      </div>
    </div> 
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$("body").on("swiperight",function(){
  console.log('swipe happend, what to do now');
});
```

```js
$("body").on("swiperight",function(){
  console.log('swipe happend, what to do now');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>The swiperight Event</h1>
      </div>
    
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>If you swipe me in the right direction, I will disappear.</p>
        <p>Swipe me in the right direction!</p>
        <p>Swipe me in the right direction, too!</p>
      </div>
    
      <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer Text</h1>
      </div>
    </div> 
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

```
$(document).on('swipeleft', 'body', function(event){ });
$(document).on('swiperight', 'body', function(event){ });
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get any of the above to work.  However, this does

```
jQuery(function(){

  jQuery( "body" ).on( "swipeleft", swipeleftHandler );
  jQuery( "body" ).on( "swiperight", swiperightHandler );

  function swipeleftHandler( event ){
    // do stuff here
  }
  function swiperightHandler( event ){
    // do stuff here
  }
});
```